# Register singletons as collection of Interfaces with Prism 7

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, ioc-container, prism-7

I am converting a Prim 6 using MEF for IOC to Prism 7 Unity since MEF is not longer supported.  The biggest difference I have to contend with is the presumption in MEF that everything is singleton by default while Unity tends to assume the opposite.

I have most of it converted but one thing I ran into was having a constructor reference a singleton via collections.  For example, I have these interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IAppService { }

public interface IDebugService : IAppService { }
public class DebugService : IDebugService { }

public interface IOtherService : IAppService { }
public class OtherService : IOtherService { }
```

with `DebugService` and `OtherService` registers as singletons and mapped to both of their respective interfaces:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IModuleMessageBus, ModuleMessageBus>();

    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<DebugService>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDebugService, DebugService>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IAppService, DebugService>(typeof(DebugService).FullName);

    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<OtherService>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IOtherService, OtherService>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IAppService, OtherService>(typeof(OtherService).FullName);
}
```

The intent is `DebugService`/`IDebugService` and `OtherService`/`IOtherService` are registered/mapped as singletons which would return the same instance but `IAppService` as named instances of each so there can be more one `IAppService` registered.  Any call to get a collection would include the singleton of `DebugService` and `OtherService`.

The second part is what is giving me a problem.  Getting a collection of `IAppService` in a constructor always generates new instances.  So, if I have this:

```
public SomeViewModel(
    IModuleMessageBus messageBus
    , IDebugService debugService
    , IEnumerable<IAppService> services
)   {   }

public AnotherViewModel(
    IModuleMessageBus messageBus
    , IDebugService debugService
)   {   }
```

What will happen is the constructor for `DebugService` will be hit twice.  Once for the `IDebugService` injection for BOTH constructors and again specifically for the `IEnumerable`.  If I comment out `, IEnumerable<IAppService> services` then it is only hit once.  How can I have one and only one instance of the services but still register them with other interfaces to obtain as collections.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Haukinger's response, I took a look at Prism's github since that overload is not exposed by the module.  Turns out they are adding it in 7.2.  THe latest preview (5 days old as of the time of this writing) has it merged in:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1668

---

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately, it still seems to be a problem.  I changed the registration to this and it still is hit twice:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<DebugService>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDebugService, DebugService>();
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterSingleton(
    typeof(IAppService)
    , typeof(DebugService)
    , typeof(DebugService).FullName
);

containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<OtherService>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IOtherService, OtherService>();
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterSingleton(
    typeof(IAppService)
    , typeof(OtherService)
    , typeof(OtherService).FullName
);
```

Upgrading PRISM to the preview will not make a difference since it still references the same unity versions.  But updating the unity packages will break Prism since they contain braking changes (looks like in Unity.Abstraction).

---

**ANSWER THANKS TO HAUKINGER**

Haukinger put me on the right track so give him a bump if this helps!!

Since prism 7 (currently) is using Unit Container 5.8 / Unity Abstraction 3, we have to use the `InjectionFactory` which is marked as obsolete and will soon be removed.  To get the above to work, I had to do this (soooo gross):

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<DebugService>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDebugService, DebugService>();
//Manually map the registration resolve
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IAppService>(
    typeof(DebugService).FullName
    , new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<DebugService>())
);

containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<OtherService>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IOtherService, OtherService>();
//Manually map the registration resolve
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IAppService>(
    typeof(OtherService).FullName
    , new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<OtherService>())
);
```

Comment: You could use a singleton pattern and have the public constructor return the same static instance every time.

Comment: @CarlPease  Thanks for the suggestion.  That would work but would require refactoring dozens of classes which I really wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register transiently like this

> `containerRegistry.Register<IAppService, DebugService>(typeof(DebugService).FullName);`

then resolving a new `DebugService` every time is expected behavior.

If you want only one `DebugService` instance to exist, register it as singleton:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppService, DebugService>(typeof(DebugService).FullName);
```

For a detailed description of what Unity 5 does here and why it does so (unlike older versions), have a look at [this wiki page on github](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/wiki#the-solution).

EDIT: it's a bit more complicated, and the solution looks quite a bit workaround-ish...

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Service>();
container.RegisterFactory<ISingleInterface>( x => x.Resolve<Service>() );
container.RegisterFactory<IEnumeratedInterface>( "service", x => x.Resolve<Service>() );
```

This is all for `IUnityContainer`, you have to get it from the `IContainerRegistry`by use of the `GetContainer()` extension.

Further reading [at unity's github](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues/154). Depending on your unity version, you can/have to use `InjectionFactory` instead of `RegisterFactory`.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually looked for an overload like that but it turns out it is not exposed by Prism.  I will edit my question to include a reference.

Comment: BTW, you do not need to rely on the crappy `IContainerRegistry`, just call the `GetContainer()` extension and configure the underlying `IUnityContainer` directly.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful actually.  I may have jumped the gun before marking you answer since it seems to still seems to not work, sorry about that.  This is with Prism referencing unity 5.8 so I assume it is new enough based on you URL.

Comment: Got it to work, actually, I had the problem myself a while ago, that's where this github-issue is coming from :-) This question looked strangely familiar from the beginning...

Comment: Thats it!  Thanks again for the help.  Ya, that it totally nasty!  But it gets the job done.